# Why Files.walk(path, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS) not following links?

Tags: java, symlink

On my Mac OS X, I have the following file hierarchy:

```
(base) bohaoli@bunnyBoom-2:~/Desktop/tuto/tuto_link$ tree

.
├── a
│   └── b
│       ├── c
│       │   └── d
│       └── link -> /Users/bohaoli/Desktop/tuto/tuto_link/e/f/g/h/cousin.txt
└── e
    └── f
        └── g
            └── h
                └── cousin.txt
```

But the last two lines of the following code

```
Path path = Paths.get("/Users/bohaoli/Desktop/tuto/tuto_link/a");
Files.walk(path, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS).forEach(System.out::println);
Files.walk(path).forEach(System.out::println);
```

give the same result:

```
/Users/bohaoli/Desktop/tuto/tuto_link/a
/Users/bohaoli/Desktop/tuto/tuto_link/a/b
/Users/bohaoli/Desktop/tuto/tuto_link/a/b/link
/Users/bohaoli/Desktop/tuto/tuto_link/a/b/c
/Users/bohaoli/Desktop/tuto/tuto_link/a/b/c/d
```

Why links are not followed even if I provided the FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS option?

Comment: If you want to see the actual FOLLOW_LINKS in action, change `./a/b/link` to be a symlink to `./e/f` for instance. Then if you run again your code, you'll see the difference.

Comment: The links were followed, you just can't see the difference since your link is not a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS` is for symbolic directory links only. What would you expect to be the result otherwise (you already have `/Users/bohaoli/Desktop/tuto/tuto_link/a/b/link` in your results). You can handle file symlinks with these methods when visiting a node:

```
boolean Files.isSymbolicLink(file.toPath())
File getCanonicalFile()
String getCanonicalPath()
```

See [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html) and [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html) documentation.